# Dynamically generated dropdown list is not displaying options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a dropdown list that is being cleared and new options added based on the value of another dropdown list. The options are being cleared just fine, and it seems to be adding the new values. However, all the options are just blank (whitespace). Does the element need to be refreshed somehow?

**My Code**

```js
success: function (data) {
  removeOptions();
  const array = data.Content;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $("<option />", {
      Val: array[i].caId,
      Text: `${array[i].Id} - ${array[i].Name}`
    }).appendTo("#CustomerAccountId");
  }
}
```

[Picture of Inspecting the element. You can see that the options/values are there, just not showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1xCI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a Text attribute, but not actually putting text in the option tag. Try this:

```
success: function (data) 
{
  removeOptions();
  const array = data.Content;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
  {
      $("<option />", {
          Val: array[i].caId
      }).text(${array[i].Id} + " - " + ${array[i].Name}).appendTo("#CustomerAccountId");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, that was it! Thanks so much!